# multiple onclick events on a single div - changing the div border colors - javascript

Tags: javascript, html, onclick, mouseevent

I've put this code inside the div:

```
onclick="this.style.border='solid 1px red';"
```

How to insert multiple onclick events which would trigger changes of border colors - for example 1st click - red, 2nd click - blue, 3rd click - reset?

This is exactly what I need - changes of the one particular div with multiple onclick events, not improvisations with multiple divs.

edit:

I also have other actions called with onclick + I have onmouseenter and onmouseleave events inside of the same div. Everything work as it should, I only can't get multiple onclick events to work.

I can't get any of these functions to work and I can't tell why. Maybe because I have more actions and events, or maybe it's up to Wordpress?

(I put a function in the header area inside of `<script></script>`)

I thought this will be easier than playing a sound, but surprisingly sounds were a piece of cake and this seems to be a real challenge...

can somebody help?

edit2: It was up to Wordpres. Now I know how to make proper functions to work.

**edit3**: I've edited a little solution posted by user1875968, and I finally got exactly what I want (with proper reset):

```
var linkClick = 1; 
  function update_link(obj){ 
  if (linkClick == 1){obj.style.border = 'solid 1px red'};
  if (linkClick == 2){obj.style.border = 'solid 1px blue'};
  if (linkClick == 3){obj.style.border = 'solid 1px green'};
  if (linkClick >3 ) {obj.style.border = 'solid 1px #555555'; linkClick=0};
  linkClick++; 
}
```

thanks everybody for your help ;)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
<script> 
var linkClick = 0; 
  function update_link(obj){ 
  if (linkClick == 0){obj.style.border = 'solid 1px red'};
  if (linkClick == 1){obj.style.border = 'solid 1px blue'};
  if (linkClick >1 ) {obj.style.border = 'solid 1px red'; linkClick=0};
  linkClick++; 
}
</script>
```

HTML

```
<a href='#' onclick='update_link(this)'> my link </a>
```

Comment: Works! This is almost exactly what I need. Almost, because the reset part is problematic - it doesn't restore the state which was before the 1st click (linkClick == 0) so I need 1 extra click in order to "close the circle". Do you have a solution for this?

Comment: Nevermind, I've figured this out for myself and posted the solution. btw, I really like this approach, can't be more clean and simple. thanks ;)

Answer (score 2):

you can make use of functions and css classes.

Identify the styles you want to switch between as different classes. Let's take them as:

```
.redBorder
{
   border: 1px solid red;
}

.blueBorder
{
   border: 1px solid blue;
}

.resetBorder
{
   border: none;
}
```

declare a function on the click event of the div:

```
onclick="switchBorder(this);"
```

Inside the function, use a switch case on the div class:

```
function switchBorder(divObj)
{
   prevClass = divObj.className;

   switch( prevClass )
   {
       case 'redBorder':
           divObj.className = "blueBorder"
           break;

       case 'blueBorder':
           divObj.className = "resetBorder"
           break;

       case 'resetBorder':
           divObj.className = "redBorder"
           break;

    }
}
```

Hope that helps. :)

Edit: syntax mistake.

Comment: Like the use of classes here. Will fall over if multiple classes are added to those elements though

Comment: This is so nice, sticks to the requirement of the new style being inherently dependent on the old style, and not on how many clicks have been made (to my understanding, at least).

Comment: Correct but it was only to handle the case as mentioned by @weaponx.

Comment: seems clean and logical to me but I didn't managed to get this to work. I guess I'm doing something wrong. I use wordpress and I've copied your style into <style></style> and your function into <script></script> ant put it both in the header area. can you please help me with this? (yes, I am a newbie in coding)

Comment: maybe it's also worth of mentioning that I have more onclick events, same as onmouseenter and onmouseleave ones, and everything works smooth except for multiple onclick...

Comment: Yeah, it was up to Wordpress. Now I know how to make proper functions to work. But your solution still doesn't work for me - I've tried to put your css in several places and files without success...

Comment: Did you put the css class in your html element like <div class="redBorder" onclick="switchBorder(this)">text</div>. Please note I've made an edit.

Answer (score 0):

The only way i could think of is changing the on-click event every time it's fired like:

```
x.onclick = method1;

function method1()
{
x.onclick = method2;
}

funbction method2()
{
x.onclick = method3;
}

function method3()
{
x.onclick = method1;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can make use of integers

```
onclick="my_function()"
```

and then:

```
function my_function(){
  i++;
  if(i == 1){
    //red
  }
  if(i == 2){
    //blue
  }
  if(i == 3){
    i = 0;
    // reset
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

it's best to use javascript for this.

```
var clicks = 0;

function changeBorder() {
    if(++clicks > 2) clicks = 1;
    switch (clicks) {
        case 1 : { this.style.border='solid 1px red';}; break;
        case 2 : { this.style.border='solid 1px blue';}; break;
    }
}
```

But you have to adapt on the "this" element. (i don't know which one it is, use getElementById)

and use in HTML,

```
onclick="changeBorder()"
```

Answer (score 0):

Something like this. Presuming the default border is "1px solid black". This can be extended to contain as many changes and colors as you want.

```
function changeBorder(ele){

 var colors = ["1px solid black", "1px solid red", "1px solid blue"];
 var curInd = colors.indexOf(ele.style.border);

 if(curInd != colors.length-1){  //If the current color isn't the last one
    //Next color
    ele.style.border = colors[curInd++];
 } else {
    //Reset to first color
    ele.style.border = colors[0];
 }
}
```

**NOTE:** array.indexOf is an ECMAscript 5 implementation for older browsers please include the shim found [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/indexOf)

Answer (score 0):

Try using a global variable like `colorCode` and initialize it to zero—`colorCode=0`

And call a function `onClick="ChangeBGColor()"`

```
function ChangeBGColor()
{
    colorcode++;
    var color='';

    if (colorcode==1)
    {
        color='red';
    }
    else if (colorcode==2)
    {
        color='blue';    
    }
    else
    {
        colorCode=0; /*Reset to zero if colorCode =3 or more*/
        color='gray';
    }

    this.style.border="'solid 1px "+color+ "';" /* Need to correctly apply style for the specific contol*/
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<div id="x" onclick="Clicked"></div>
<script type="text/javascript">
   var clickno=1;
   function Clicked()
   {
      if(clickno==1)
      {
         document.getElementById('x').style.border="solid 1px red";
      }
      if(clickno==2)
      {
         document.getElementById('x').style.border="solid 1px blue";
      }
      if(clickno==3)
      {
         document.getElementById('x').style.border="solid 1px red";
         clickno=1;
      }
      clickno++;
   }
</script>
```

Comment: It works, but only for the one specific div. thanks for the help.

Comment: @weaponx I f you want to use it global just type in the attributes of `body` tag's `onclick`