# change div background color on shift + click (javascript)?

Tags: javascript, html, onclick, click, shift

I already have `onclick` event for changing border color of a div on mouse click.

I want to be able to change background color separately on shift + click, without changing border colors.

How to achieve this?

**edit:**

the current code for multiple clicks and shift+click:

```
<script> 
var linkClick = 1; 
  function update_x(obj){ 
  if (linkClick == 1){obj.style.border = 'solid 1px #eeeeee';};
  if (linkClick == 2){obj.style.border = 'solid 1px red'};
  if (linkClick == 3){obj.style.border = 'solid 1px rgba(50, 255, 50, 1)'};
  if (linkClick == 4){obj.style.border = 'solid 1px rgba(70, 180, 255, 1)'};
  if (linkClick == 5){obj.style.border = 'solid 1px yellow'};
  if (linkClick >5 ) {obj.style.border = 'solid 1px #555555'; linkClick=0};
  linkClick++; 
}
</script>
<script>
function changeDivColor (event) {
    event = event || window.event;
    var myDiv = document.getElementById("b14")
    if (event.shiftKey == true) {
        myDiv.style.backgroundColor = "blue";  
    }
}
window.onload = function () {
    document.getElementById("b14").onclick = function (event) {
        changeDivColor (event);
        update_x(this);
    }
}
</script>
```

**edit2 - solved by Jeffman**

Comment: What kind of event is shift+click? the user will press the key 'shift' and then click? Where have u seen such an application?

Comment: Post the code you have already and we help you from there.

Comment: @SangramSingh, what's wrong with SHIFT + Click?

Comment: event.shiftKey == true

Comment: can u give an example of where u've seen it being used? (for my reference)

Comment: I know a lot of people don't like W3Schools, but here: http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/event_shiftkey.asp

Comment: @SangramSingh, choosing multiple files in most computer systems is done with shift+click (windows & mac for example).

Comment: @ Sergio - here is the code I have for onclick changing borders: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18044757/disable-mouse-event-on-1st-and-re-enable-the-same-on-3rd-click-javascript

Comment: OK, I posted my update. I think it does what you want, but I'm not sure how the borders are supposed to work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Latest code. See it work here: http://jsfiddle.net/jeffman/Y3QET/

```
var linkClick = 1; 
function update_x(obj) { 
    if (linkClick == 1){obj.style.border = 'solid 1px #eeeeee';};
    if (linkClick == 2){obj.style.border = 'solid 1px red'};
    if (linkClick == 3){obj.style.border = 'solid 1px rgba(50, 255, 50, 1)'};
    if (linkClick == 4){obj.style.border = 'solid 1px rgba(70, 180, 255, 1)'};
    if (linkClick == 5){obj.style.border = 'solid 1px yellow'};
    if (linkClick >5 ) {obj.style.border = 'solid 1px #555555'; linkClick=0};
    linkClick++; 
}

function changeDivColor (el, event) {
    if (event.shiftKey == true) {
        el.style.backgroundColor = "blue";  
    }
}
window.onload = function () {
    var i = 1, len = 5; // len is the number of elements using the b1 id pattern
    for (i; i <= len; i++) {
        document.getElementById("b" + i).onclick = function (event) {
            event = event || window.event;
            changeDivColor (this, event);
            update_x(this); // or whatever your other function is.
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: simple and it works, but it also disables my other function related to onclick (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18044757/disable-mouse-event-on-1st-and-re-enable-the-same-on-3rd-click-javascript). I want to have both to work separately.

Comment: The official way around that is described here: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/EventTarget.addEventListener

Comment: to be honest, I have no idea what to do. can you write a function which would go around this conflict?

Comment: Just to be clear, you want both handlers on the same element's click event? It's certainly possible, I just need to be sure.

Comment: Also, which element gets its background changed. The element that gets clicked, or a different element?

Comment: Yes, I need both on the same div and only the clicked div gets affected.

Comment: Basically this works, but with or without shift the borders keeps changing colors with clicks. I was thinking about a complete separation of click and shift+click. Also, since I have a lot of divs - how multiple divs can be called in function (for ex. id from x1 to x100)? Or how can your functions be called inside of a div?

Comment: Please post the final code for `update_link` at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18015562/multiple-onclick-events-on-a-single-div-changing-the-div-border-colors-javas so I can fit it all together.

Comment: Wait. It looks like you did post your final code. I'll try that. If you've changed it, though, please do post it again.

Comment: this is great. that issue with borders is still there, but it's not that big of a deal (complete separation is maybe not possible in js). just one more question - how can I use other keys (letters, numbers) beside alt, shift and ctrl? event.keycode = true (where exactly goes keycode - for ex. 65 (letter A)?)

Comment: event.keyCode returns the number of the key. Here is a good table the matches the numbers to the keys: http://www.webonweboff.com/tips/js/event_key_codes.aspx

Comment: I've tried to put  if (event.keyCode == 65)  and it won't work.

Comment: Where did you put it? If you put it in update_x , then the function definition has to look like `function update_x(obj, event) {` and you must execute it like `update_x(this, event)`. If that's not it, show me.

Comment: function changeDivColor (el, event) {
    if (event.shiftKey == true) {
        el.style.backgroundColor = "blue";  
    }
    if (event.keyCode == 65) {
        el.style.backgroundColor = "red";  
    }
}

Comment: do you know how to call a keyCode inside of this function? or how would you write a separate function for the same purpose, but with using a+click instead of shift/alt/ctrl+click. whatever I've tried it doesn't work. This is just one more thing that I need.

Comment: I'm pretty sure you can only do that with modifier keys (shift/alt/ctrl). Otherwise, you get a keydown event and then a keypress event firing, but not simultaneously with the click event. They would register as separate events.

Comment: Ok man, thanks a lot for your help and patience. I guess I can survive without a/s/d + click functionality. Maybe multiple shift+click is possible but I can survive without that either. If you are in the mood and have time - post the code update which would handle that. If you don't that's ok - you already helped a lot.

Comment: Hey Jeffman, since your help really meant a lot to me, I would like to repay you in some way. I have one simple idea - one-sided (on me), but beneficial for the both of us - if you have a site / blog / anything and if you are interested in details, I'm here - x_xs1@yahoo.com

Answer (score 1):

In your `onclick`, make sure you refer to the `event`, e.g. if you're using an attribute:

```
<div onclick="clickHandler(event);" ... >
```

or if you're assigning it later:

```
divElement.onclick = function(event) {
    event = event || window.event; // Support for older IE
    // ...
};
```

or if you're really using `addEventListener` and just said `onclick` as a kind of shorthand:

```
divelement.addEventListener("click", function(event) {
    // ...
}, false);
```

Then you can refer to the `event.shiftKey` flag to tell whether Shift is down.

[Live Example](http://jsbin.com/ediral/1) | [Live Source](http://jsbin.com/ediral/1/edit)

More in [the spec](http://www.w3.org/TR/DOM-Level-3-Events/#event-type-click).

Comment: can you please write the function for changing background colors instead of changing text? or a function which would be called with onclick="clickHandler(event);"? I've tried to implement these on my own and I can't get it to work.

Answer (score 0):

Javascript.net has an explanation of how to do what you need at http://www.javascripter.net/faq/ctrl_alt.htm